# vim включить отображение вводимых действий

Tags: vim, vimrc

Когда запускаю vim от рута, в рулере есть интересная штука которая отображает все нажимаемые действия, будь то смена буфера, поиск, или создание отметки, не подскажет кто как оно вообще называется или как включить это к себе в статусную строку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

включить режим отображения частично введённой команды в последней строке экрана: `set showcmd` (`set sc`).

отключить: `set noshowcmd` (`set nosc`).

---

подробнее: [`:help showcmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27)

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно ли перенести её в статусную строку?

Comment: насколько я понимаю — нет. из элементарного соображения: статусная строка формируется указанной пользователем командой (иногда — довольно «тяжеловесной»), и выполнение этой команды после **каждого** нажатия клавиши могло бы серьёзно ухудшить интерактивность работы.